# Single class modules in a Python package

Tags: python, namespaces

I am making a python package where I currently have a structure as below:

`application/utils.py`

```
class settings():
  function foo():
    bla bla bla

class debug():
  function bar():
    bla bla bla
```

Then in other modules the import of the settings and debug classes can be done as below:

```
import application.utils.settings
import application.utils.debug
```

But now, the classes are getting pretty big and I would like to put them in separates files.

`application/utils/settings.py`

```
class settings():
  function foo():
    bla bla bla
```

`application/utils/debug.py`

```
class debug():
  function bar():
    bla bla bla
```

In that case, importing the debug and settings classes would be as below:

```
import application.utils.settings.settings
import application.utils.debug.debug
```

That I feel quite unnatural.
Is it the right way to do that or am I missing something?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can write in `application/utils/__init__.py`:

```
from application.utils.settings import Settings
from application.utils.debug import Debug
```

Then you will access `Settings` and `Debug` classes shorter

```
from application.utils import Settings
from application.utils import Debug
```

Don't name your classes and modules the same. Read [PEP8](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#naming-conventions) about naming convention

Answer (score 0):

Import your classes in your `utils/__init__.py` file and import them as you used to.